# How to add 3 labels in VB 6

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to add these 3 labels together. 2 of which correspond to global variables and the 3rd corresponds to a tax calculation of the 2 global variables. When I use the program it's only adding the two global variables and not the final tax label.

```
Sub bill()
    Total = Val(lblRefreshmentPrice) + Val(lblTicketprice)
    lblBillTaxPrice = Format(Total * 0.13, "Currency")
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    lblRefreshmentPrice = RefreshmentPrice
    lblTicketprice = Ticketprice
    lblFinalTotalPrice = Val(lblRefreshmentPrice) + Val(lblTicketprice) + Val(lblBillTaxPrice)
    Call bill
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that _all_ the code?

Comment: that is only the code for the calculation but there is more, what im trying to do is calculate the tax for the 2 global variables and then add the 2 global variables And the tax i calculated

Comment: Using `Val(lblRefreshmentPrice)` to get the value is bad. You should be using the underlying numeric value (RefreshmentPrice) when doing arithmetic. If you *must* take a value from a label, you should be converting the text to a number like this `Val(lblRefreshmentPrice.Caption)`.

Comment: Is this what you mean? 
Sub bill()

Total = Val(lblRefreshmentPrice.Caption) + Val(lblTicketprice.Caption)
lblBillTaxPrice = Format(Total * 0.13, "Currency")

End Sub                                                    Private Sub Form_Load()                        lblRefreshmentPrice = RefreshmentPrice

lblTicketprice = Ticketprice                    lblFinalTotalPrice = Val(lblRefreshmentPrice.Caption) + Val(lblTicketprice.Caption) + Val(lblBillTaxPrice.Caption)

Call bill


End Sub @Verdolino

Comment: @Verdolino do you want me to change Val(lblRefreshmentPrice) to Val(lblRefreshmentPrice.Caption) for  calculating the tax or for the sub code "bill"??

Comment: @Shivampatel Just see my answer. I made a simple app and put all your labels on my form. I believe it does what you want. Try it out and give me some feedback.

Comment: Off topic, but you may want to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319561/risks-around-relying-on-visual-basic-6-0-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's not working for you, I just cleaned it up.

```
Private RefreshmentPrice As Currency
Private TicketPrice As Currency
Private BillTaxPrice As Currency
Private FinalTotalPrice As Currency
Private Total As Currency

Const TaxRate As Double = 0.13


Sub bill()
    ' calculate total before tax
    Total = RefreshmentPrice + TicketPrice
    ' calculate tax
    BillTaxPrice = Total * TaxRate
    ' calculate total price with tax
    FinalTotalPrice = RefreshmentPrice + TicketPrice + BillTaxPrice
    ' set labels
    lblRefreshmentPrice.Caption = Format(RefreshmentPrice, "Currency")
    lblTicketprice.Caption = Format(TicketPrice, "Currency")
    lblFinalTotalPrice.Caption = Format(FinalTotalPrice, "Currency")
    lblBillTaxPrice.Caption = Format(BillTaxPrice, "Currency")
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' set up globals (for debug)
    RefreshmentPrice = 8
    TicketPrice = 50
    ' calculate and set labels
    bill
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry @Verdolino if i was confusing but what i need help with is adding my 3 labels.The only things that are adding up is the ticketprice and refreshmentprice.

Comment: It's all in there. Note that I am adding numbers, not labels. Then I set the labels.

Comment: So i tried to use it but the program is telling me that Format(RefreshmentPrice) is not a defined variable @Verdolino

Comment: I defined it at the top of my code. You could do `Dim RefreshmentPrice As Currency` in your method. I assumed this was one of your globals...

Comment: By default, VB6 allows you to use variables without declaring them, which can lead to run-time errors. It is good practice to add `Option Explicit` as the first line in your code file. This will tell the compiler to make sure that you have declared all variables before using them.

Comment: So i figured out how to Add the 3 labels but the tax is always being calculated to 7.54 no matter what the prices for the other 2 labels

Comment: In order to debug it (i don't have your globals defined), I had set `RefreshmentPrice = 8` and `TicketPrice = 50`. Just remove that so your globals retain their values

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH all i did was switch your code around a bit and everything works now.